# Xcode Navigation Header Disappears

Tags: xcode, navigation, xcode7.1

My Xcode navigation header (for several projects) is constantly disappearing. Especially when I go to the other Xcode projects.

How do I get it back?

It looks like this:

Also tried going to View -> Show Tool Bar & Show Tab Bar and this is what happened:

[image]

My current solution is to quit Xcode and then restart it so that the top header comes back. It's more annoying and strange than a massive issue. Hopefully it doesn't become a permanent problem.

Would still like to get rid of this!

Answer (score 0):

This should get you squared away

[image]

Comment: Hey, I just updated the answer. I tried doing exactly that and the above image is what I got. My current solution is to quit Xcode and then restart it and it comes back. It's more annoying and strange than a massive issue. Hopefully it doesn't become one anyways!